# Unable to select element from dropdown within span Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, dropdown

When trying to read a specific value from dropdown which is in span. It throws error "element should have been select but was span"

I am tried reading the element, click the element and then try reading the text but nothing works

```
protected By entityIDdrpdwn => By.XPath("//span[@class='k-input']");
string value = "Campaign";            

ClickElement(entityIDdrpdwn);                   
SelectValueFromDropdown(entityIDdrpdwn,value);
```

[image]

I expect the the element from dropdown "Campaign" should be selected but it throws error

Answer (score 0):

The method `SelectValueFromDropdown(entityIDdrpdwn,value)` presumably uses `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select` class which deals with elements that are present inside the  `select` html tag. Elements belonging to the `select` tag contain attributes like `name` , `value` etc. and the `Select` class interacts with them. This is the reason you are getting an error *element should have been select but was span*.

You can try to get the `span` element and then get the underlying value.

Also, you can refer to https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html to understand more about the `Select` class as this webpage does have good visualizations.

Comment: I tried to get the span. The problem is that the value within span changed based on the selecting which is like : <span>::before "Value"</span>. So when trying to find and select that specific value using span which contains text, it throws an error- Could not find element. for eg: FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='k-input'][contains(text(),'AD'")]);